# find out how many (posix) tar header blocks a file will require

Tags: tar, tape

Posix (pax) tar uses extended headers to allow long filenames etc..

Is there a way to find out how many 512 byte blocks will be used for the header for a particular file (before actually running the tar command)

Am looking at implementing a byte range restore function from tape, so in order to get the exact bytes specified I need to know the offset from the beginning of the tar archive. Therefore I need to know how many blocks were used for the header (but without having to read them - since that will slow down the operation)

Comment: You should give a more detailed explanation about what you intend to do.Your current question is not precise enough to know whether `star -c -v -block-number ...` together with `star -x -one-file mtskip=# ...` would exactly match your requirement. See http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/star.1.html